# Correspondence relationship between the URDF file and the state of MultibodyPlant in drake

Tags: drake

In the case of [Compass Gait Limit Cycle](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/exercises/simple_legs/compass_gait_limit_cycle.ipynb), the `system` is obtained from `'models/compass_gait_limit_cycle.urdf'` and the `context` is from `CreateDefaultContext()`.
These define the configuration vector q as [x, y, θ_1, θ_2]^T in my recognition.

In the case that URDF model is more complicated(e.g. having several branched structures), I could obtain the `system` and the `context` as the same way, but I could not understand which component of q is corresponding to the `joint` in URDF file.

Are there some way to know the correspondence relationship?
The best way I need is get the index of q from the name of the `joint` from URDF file.
But anything is ok if I could know the correspondence.

In addition, I want to know the way to rearrange the order of components of q(and also of qd and qdd).
For example, in the case of compass gait, the default order is [x, y, θ_1, θ_2] and the new order is [θ_1, θ_2, x, y] or something like this.

Perhaps, creating `context` by myself is the best way.
But I do not understand the `context` perfectly, so I need some instruction to crate it.

I am using pydrake on ubuntu 20.04.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MultibodyPlant` (loaded from URDF), then MultibodyPlant controls the order of the variables in the context state vector. As you say, it is intended that you access them from the joint accessors.  In python, I have a simple method that packs them into a `namedview`, which is very convenient for working with them: https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/ee7a2041047772f823d0dc0dd32e992196b2a670/underactuated/utils.py#L32-L86

You can see how I use this in a number of examples in the underactuated notes.  Perhaps the [littledog example](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/master/examples/littledog.ipynb) shows it best.

If you want to use them in a different order in a different system, then I would recommend adding something like a [`MatrixGain`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_matrix_gain.html) system that implements a permutation matrix to rearrange them.